# How to filter the duplicate rows with complex scenarios

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, reduce

I would like to filter duplicate rows with some complex scenarios.

**For example 1:**

ID and Code ID are the same, and the Status is either "Not Reservable" or "Reservable", we will remove the ID and Code ID that have the status of "Reservable"

**For example 2:**

ID and Code ID are the same, and the Status is either "Completed" or "Reservable", we will remove the ID and Code ID that have the Status of "Completed"

**For example 3:**

If 2 IDs are the same, and the Code ID is different, we will display both in the list

```
var new data = [{
    ID: 150042379,
    Name: Cake 1234
    Status: 'Not Reservable'
    Code ID: 302
  },
  {
    ID: 150042379,
    Name: Cake 1234
    Status: 'Reservable'
    Code ID: 302
  },
  {
    ID: 150042379,
    Name: Bread 1236 Ticket
    Status: 'Reservable'
    Code ID: 391
  },
  {
    ID: 150053213,
    Name: Bread Basic 8
    Status: 'Reservable'
    Code ID: 201
  },
  {
    ID: 150053213,
    Name: Bread Basic 6
    Status: 'Reservable'
    Code ID: 301
  },
  {
    ID: 150054121,
    Name: Bread Basic 16
    Status: 'Not Reservable'
    Code ID: 202
  },
  {
    ID: 150054121,
    Name: Bread Basic 16
    Status: 'Reservable'
    Code ID: 202
  },
  {
    ID: 150057599,
    Name: Bread Riche
    Status: 'Reservable'
    Code ID: 232
  },
]
```

---

So the result that I want:

```
var filter_new_data = [{
    ID: 150042379,
    Name: Cake 1234
    Status: 'Not Reservable'
    Code ID: 302
  },
  {
    ID: 150042379,
    Name: Bread 1236 Ticket
    Status: 'Reservable'
    Code ID: 391
  },
  {
    ID: 150053213,
    Name: Bread Basic 8
    Status: 'Reservable'
    Code ID: 201
  },
  {
    ID: 150053213,
    Name: Bread Basic 6
    Status: 'Reservable'
    Code ID: 301
  },
  {
    ID: 150054121,
    Name: Bread Basic 16
    Status: 'Not Reservable'
    Code ID: 202
  },
  {
    ID: 150057599,
    Name: Bread Riche
    Status: 'Reservable'
    Code ID: 232
  },
]
```

---

This is my current code and I stuck half way

```
filter_new_data = Object.values(new_data.reduce((acc, value) => {
        if (acc[value.ID]) {
          if (acc[value.ID].STATUS === 'Not Reservable') {
            acc[value.ID] = acc[value.ID]
          } else if (acc[value.ID].STATUS === 'Reservable') {
            acc[value.ID] = acc[value.ID]
          } else {
            acc[value.ID] = value
          }
        } else {
          acc[value.ID] = value
        }
        return acc
      }, {}))
```

Comment: `If 2 IDs are the same, and the Code ID is different, we will display both in the list`. What if `2 IDs are same and Code ID`s are also same?

Comment: @randomSoul That's in the first two examples.

Comment: My question would be, where are you stuck, you're on the right track

Comment: You will need to use a combination of `ID` and `Code ID` as the key in your lookup map, if both are the uniqueness criteria

Comment: Have you tested the input of `var new data`? And then once you figure that error test `data.code ID`. Or any value of `Name`? How did you test your function with input such as it is?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making object that combines the 2 values of `ID` and `CodeId` as keys then you only need to check status on duplicates and the singles will take care of themselves

Once full loop complete get the values from the object

```js
 const NO_RESERVE = 'Not Reservable', COMPLETE ='Completed';

const tmp = data.reduce((a,c)=>{
   const {ID, Code_ID, Status} = c,
         key = `${ID}|${Code_ID}`;// will isolate singles automatically
         
   if(!a[key]){
         // not a duplicate yet
         a[key] = c;
   }else{     
      //duplicate logic here may need some verification. Not 100% clear about priorities
      if(Status === NO_RESERVE && a[key].Status !== NO_RESERVE){
         a[key].Status = NO_RESERVE
      }else if(Status !== COMPLETE && a[key].Status === COMPLETE){
         a[key].Status = Status
      }   
   }
   return a;
   
},{})

console.log(Object.values(tmp))
```

```html
<script>
  var data = [{
      ID: 150042379,
      Name: 'Cake 1234',
      Status: 'Not Reservable',
      Code_ID: 302
    },
    {
      ID: 150042379,
      Name: 'Cake 1234',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      Code_ID: 302
    },
    {
      ID: 150042379,
      Name: 'Bread 1236 Ticket',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      Code_ID: 391
    },
    {
      ID: 150053213,
      Name: 'Bread Basic 8',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      Code_ID: 201
    },
    {
      ID: 150053213,
      Name: 'Bread Basic 6',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      Code_ID: 301
    },
    {
      ID: 150054121,
      Name: 'Bread Basic 16',
      Status: 'Not Reservable',
      Code_ID: 202
    },
    {
      ID: 150054121,
      Name: 'Bread Basic 16',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      Code_ID: 202
    },
    {
      ID: 150057599,
      Name: 'Bread Riche',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      Code_ID: 232
    },
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe add:

const STATUSES = {
    'Not Reservable': 30,
    'Reservable': 20,
    'Completed': 10,
}

const statusFilter = (current, stored) => (!stored || STATUSES[stored.Status] < STATUSES[stored.Status]) ? current : stored

And then replace code between key and return with: 

a[key] = statusFilter(c, a[key])

haven't tested it

Comment: hi @charlietfl, thanks for your suggestion. I have a doubt, lets say I have 2 IDs with same Code IDs and the status is 'Completed' & 'Reservable', it should display the IDs with status of 'Reservable' instead. Should i change the logic in else statement ?

Comment: Yes I wasn't sure about those comparisons

Answer (score 1):

I took a similar approach to @charlietfl but he was faster. ;)

```
const STATUSES = {
    'Not Reservable': 30,
    'Reservable': 20,
    'Completed': 10,
}

var dataMap = new Map()

data.forEach((ele)=>{
    let {ID, 'Code ID': codeID, Status} = ele
    let key = `${ID}:${codeID}`
    if (!dataMap.has(key)) {
        dataMap.set(key, ele)
    } else {
        let stored = dataMap.get(key)
        // If the current ele.Status Value greater than store.Status Value then over write
        if (STATUSES[Status] > STATUSES[stored.Status]) dataMap.set(key, ele)
    }
})
var results = Array.from(dataMap).map(ele=>ele[1])
console.log(JSON.stringify(results,null,2))
```

```js
var data = [{
      ID: 150042379,
      Name: 'Cake 1234',
      Status: 'Not Reservable',
      'Code ID': 302
    },
    {
      ID: 150042379,
      Name: 'Cake 1234',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      'Code ID': 302
    },
    {
      ID: 150042379,
      Name: 'Bread 1236 Ticket',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      'Code ID': 391
    },
    {
      ID: 150053213,
      Name: 'Bread Basic 8',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      'Code ID': 201
    },
    {
      ID: 150053213,
      Name: 'Bread Basic 6',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      'Code ID': 301
    },
    {
      ID: 150054121,
      Name: 'Bread Basic 16',
      Status: 'Not Reservable',
      'Code ID': 202
    },
    {
      ID: 150054121,
      Name: 'Bread Basic 16',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      'Code ID': 202
    },
    {
      ID: 150057599,
      Name: 'Bread Riche',
      Status: 'Reservable',
      'Code ID': 232
    },
  ]

const STATUSES = {
 'Not Reservable': 30,
 'Reservable': 20,
 'Completed': 10,
}

var dataMap = new Map()

data.forEach((ele)=>{
 let {ID, 'Code ID': codeID, Status} = ele
 let key = `${ID}:${codeID}`
 if (!dataMap.has(key)) {
  dataMap.set(key, ele)
 } else {
  let stored = dataMap.get(key)
  // If the current ele.Status Value greater than store.Status Value then over write
  if (STATUSES[Status] > STATUSES[stored.Status]) dataMap.set(key, ele)
 }
})
var results = Array.from(dataMap).map(ele=>ele[1])
console.log(JSON.stringify(results,null,2))
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking your reduce approach with the hashmap would be a good solution. The hasmap could even be stored in a db somewhere to provide more flexibility and make it user configurable.